# C++ - avoiding a multiple definition creating more problems

Tags: c++, arrays

I am breaking down some code into header and source files and I am having real trouble in avoiding a multiple definition of the array Database.

I had problems with multiple definitions of Database, which originally looked like this:

**database.h original**

```
// number of columns in row of the database
#include <cstdint>
#define DATABASE_COLS 16


int8_t Database[][DATABASE_COLS] = {
   //20x16 integer values are here, removed on StackOverflow for easier reading
};


// number of rows in the database
#define DATABASE_ROWS sizeof(Database)/sizeof(Database[0])
```

When #including database.h in application.h (and then application.h in main.cpp) I had issues with Database being multiply defined in main.cpp and application.h so I moved the contents of Database to a new file database.cpp and used the extern declaration which seemed to eliminate the issue of multiple definitions. but now, I get the error

> ./application.h(24): error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'std::int8_t [][16]'

The problem seems to lie with "DATABASE_ROWS" in all my source and header files and I can't quite work out how to get around this.

So far I have the following files involving the Database array:

**database.h**

```
#include <cstdint>
#define DATABASE_COLS 16

extern int8_t Database[][DATABASE_COLS];

// number of rows in the database
#define DATABASE_ROWS sizeof(Database)/sizeof(Database[0])
```

**database.cpp**

```
#include "database.h"
int8_t Database[][DATABASE_COLS] = {
  //20x16 integer values are here, removed on StackOverflow for easier reading
};
```

**application.h**

```
#include <cstdint>
#include "database.h"
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;


class Results {
 public:
    Results() {number = 0;}      // initial location is the start of the 'Data' data store
    void StoreResult(int32_t);   // put an item in the data store
  void EmptyResults();         // reset to point to the start of the data store
 private:
    int32_t Data[DATABASE_ROWS];  // space to store results of processing each row
  uint32_t number;              // current entry being accessed in the 'Data' data store
};
```

Could anyone please suggest a way of getting DATABASE_ROWS to work properly without multiple definition? I think I've got a few things mixed up. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use header guards into your header files.

Comment: You need include guards in your header. It's ugly and stinks, but it's also how the language works.

Comment: Thank you both - can I just check whether I should go back to the original version of database.h with the array included in it, or my second way with it defined in database.cpp?

Comment: you can only use `#define DATABASE_ROWS sizeof(Database)/sizeof(Database[0])` in places where a definition of `Database` is available, which is not the case in `application.h`. why are you using this macro in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

inline function might help to have all information in header and let deduction happen in definition, without multiple definition:

```
#define DATABASE_COLS 16
inline auto& Database()
{
    static int8_t matrix[][DATABASE_COLS] = {
         //20x16 integer values are here, removed on StackOverflow for easier reading
    };
    return matrix;
}
```

You can possibly use `std::array` instead so you have `.size()` directly.

Comment: thank you - I am using c++11 so the auto return type doesn't quite seem to work. is there an easy workaround?

Comment: Without the `auto` return type of C++14, I fear that you have to specify the return, and so drop the deduction...

Answer (score 1):

```
extern int8_t Database[][DATABASE_COLS];
```

The array is declared with unspecified size

```
// number of rows in the database
#define DATABASE_ROWS sizeof(Database)/sizeof(Database[0])
```

Since the size of the array is unspecified, its `sizeof` is unknown, hence this is not going to end well (except in `database.cpp` after it's defined with the actual size).

The usual solution is to declare the size too:

```
extern int8_t Database[][DATABASE_COLS];

extern const size_t database_rows;
```

And in `database.cpp`:

```
int8_t Database[][DATABASE_COLS] = {
  //20x16 integer values are here, removed on StackOverflow for easier reading
};

size_t const database_rows=sizeof(Database)/sizeof(Database[0]);
```

Then, all other translation units will reference this `extern`-specified size.

Of course the size of the database is no longer a (macro-evaluated) compile-time constant, so this may require a few other tweaks to the code.